# Yu Yuphoria bricked after installing custom recovery and boot file

Tags: custom-roms, unbricking, micromax-yu-yuphoria

My YU YUPHORIA got bricked while I was working with it. I want to install custom ROM into it for that I am installing custom recovery and boot file but the file that is found on Internet was not working and that's why I am stuck with company logo. I can't go into recovery mod, neither it boot, and USB debugging mode is turned off. I tried to install fresh ROM from fastboot but after installing every driver properly command prompt is showing "waiting for the device". Please sugest some way to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashing stock firmware may solve the softbrick. 
Download firmware fron this [link](http://firmwarefile.com/yu-yuphoria-yu5010a). - The link is for model **Y5010a**, since you didn't mention which model. Update with model name if it's differ.

There is 3 files, in zip format. Choose any of them, unzip it and you'll find drivers, the flash files and the flashing instructions. Install drivers and your phone should be detected.

Comment: my device is Y5010(not "a") . will this method work with usb debugging off??

Comment: Yes. Flashing doesn't require USB debugging. Did you download the file? You can follow the instructions contained therein.

Comment: yes every thing is going fine but when i write command fastboot -i 0x2a96 oem unlock it show press volume up key to continue, press volume down key to cancle. please tell me which key i have to press. and after 20seconds it show oem unlock cancelled

Comment: You're trying to unlock the bootloader. Is unlocking the bootloader required in the flashing instructions?

Comment: someone on the other form suggested me to do this before any thing

Comment: is it necessary ???

Comment: thanks sir every thing worked fine. i am happy. thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, glad I helped